# How to create a trigger in MySQL(Xampp Server) which runs a R script stored on the server?

Tags: php, mysql, r, xampp

Actually I am using R for neural networks. I have Xampp server installed on windows. I want to create a trigger on a table in MySQL, which after insertion into that table, runs a R script stored on the server itself(along with data in R object i.e .Rdata)?
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) run only SQL code. They don't have access to anything outside the MySQL daemon. The only way this could work is that there would exist a plugin for MySQL for communication with R. Plugins can make new functions available which can be used for example also in triggers. However I am not aware of such MySQL plugin for R.

Your other option is to periodically connect to MySQL from your R code to check if new data have been inserted.

If you need to know exactly which data was inserted, you can create an insert trigger for table *data*, which will create new row in separate table *newdata* with the IDs of inserted rows. Then your R code needs to check for any rows in *newdata* table, read the IDs, fetch the corresponding rows from *data* table and then remove the info about it from *newdata*.

I don't know if you know how to access MySQL from R code. One option is to use [RMySQL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html) package. Good tutorial is for example [here](http://moderndata.plot.ly/connecting-r-to-mysql-mariadb/).

Comment: thanx a lot. I used RODBC package and periodically fetched data into R from MySQL, manually.